# How do I find the probability of picking a science major and an engineering major?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

[image]

I was trying to answer part (b) like this:

There are $30 + 24 + 20 + 17 = 91$ students in total.

$\Rightarrow P(\text{science major AND engineering major}) = \dfrac{\frac{20!}{1!(20-1)!}}{\frac{91!}{1!(91-1)!}}\cdot\dfrac{\frac{30!}{1!(30-1)!}}{\frac{91!}{1!(91-1)!}}=\dfrac{20}{91}\cdot\dfrac{30}{91}=\dfrac{600}{8281}$

But this is the wrong answer. Is my method incorrect?

Comment: Please see the **Edit-Images** section of [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The computation of

$$\frac{20 \times 30}{91 \times 91} \tag1$$

is wrong for two reasons:

- In the denominator, once the first person is selected ($91$ choices) there are only $90$ people left for the second choice.  So, the denominator should be changed to $(91 \times 90)$.
- In the numerator, the computation represents the presumption that order of selection is irrelevant.  Such a presumption is okay, as long as the presumption is consistently applied **in the denominator**.

There are then two ways of accommodating the second bullet point above, both of which lead to the same computation.   It should either be

$$\frac{\binom{20}{1} \times \binom{30}{1}}{\binom{91}{2}} = \frac{20 \times 30}{\binom{91}{2}} \tag2 $$

or

$$\frac{2 \times \left[20 \times 30\right]}{91 \times 90}. \tag3 $$

In (3) above, the denominator presumes that order of selection is to be regarded as relevant.  This explains the leading factor $2$ in the numerator of (3) above, which presents that you could :

- pick an engineering major and then pick a science major 
  or
- pick a science major and then pick an engineering major.